# Logo in middle of navbar messes up the rest of the navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I tried to center all my nav items and have them horizontally aligned

However when I added my `.logo` class to the navbar, all my navigation items move down.. how do i fix this?

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nq397fby/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/AlexCharlton/nq397fby/6/

```
ul.navigation li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 40px;
    width: 20%;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.logo {
    position:relative;
    top: -30px;
    left: 6px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't fork your answer, I was in the process of fixing his logo for him to the top, I didn't see your comment. It's quite an easy task to carry out this, I'm pretty sure most web developers can do this, just because your answer is similar it doesn't mean that I copied it.

Comment: Well, I saw my name in the jsFiddle link before you edit your answer. That was just funny. I really don't care

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `position:absolute` to your class:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/nq397fby/1/)

```
ul.navigation li.logo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

That said, you may actually wish to position the child link element to create better alignment:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/nq397fby/4/)

```
ul.navigation li.logo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
}
ul.navigation li.logo a {
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:-42px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `vertical-align: top`

```
ul.navigation li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 40px;
    width: 20%;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/nq397fby/3/)

Edit : logo alignment

```
ul.navigation li.logo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -37px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Brewal/nq397fby/5/)

Comment: Thanks! But the image is still not touching the top like it should? How would I fix that

Comment: This is because you have blank space in the image itself (if you are not talking about the 6px padding of the navbar). If you don't want to change the image, position the logo to `relative` and then use `top: -40px` or something like that